# Print the last line of a file, from the CLI

Tags: linux, shell, awk, command-line-interface

How to print just the last line of a file?

Answer (score 119, accepted):

```
$ cat file | awk 'END{print}'
```

Originally answered by [Ventero](https://stackoverflow.com/users/80989)

Comment: I think the original question specified "awk" but since the question changed to be more generic, this answer made no sense. So I improved the answer a little bit. Overall, "tail" is a great solution, but "awk" might offer more nuanced control.

Answer (score 33):

Use the right tool for the job. Since you want to get the last line of a file, tail is the appropriate tool for the job, especially if you have a large file. Tail's file processing algorithm is more efficient in this case.

```
tail -n 1 file
```

If you really want to use awk,

```
awk 'END{print}' file
```

EDIT : `tail -1 file` deprecated

Answer (score 14):

Is it a must to use `awk` for this? Why not just use `tail -n 1 myFile` ?

Comment: @yael Not at all; `tail -1` will be way faster than `awk` for a large file. I tried on an ~3m line file; tail was instantaneous while awk took .44s

Comment: @yael. tail is specifically meant for processing the file from the "end". Therefore, its faster than awk. Because awk processes files from the beginning. The algorithms are different.

Comment: @yael is right - in the sence that `awk` (3B) is faster to type than `tail` (4B). When it comes to speed - well `tail` has a simpler task, and no script to parse before execution. However, @ghostdog74 is not right about "working from the end". If the input is piped, `tail` also needs to work from the beginning. And not to mention `tail -n +N`.

Comment: I wanted the first field of the last line of the file (`awk 'END { print $1 }'`). While it's not what the OP asked, the question helped and was easier to search for than "first field of last line of file"

Answer (score 8):

Find out the last line of a file:

1. Using sed (stream editor): `sed -n '$p' fileName`
2. Using tail: `tail -1 fileName`
3. using awk: `awk 'END { print }' fileName`

Answer (score 7):

You can achieve this using `sed` as well. However, I personally recommend using `tail` or `awk`.

Anyway, if you wish to do by `sed`, here are two ways:

Method 1:

```
sed '$!d' filename
```

Method2:

```
sed -n '$p' filename
```

Here, filename is the name of the file that has data to be analysed.

Comment: what's the meaning of `-n` and `$p`?

Comment: @wukong `-n` means don't print each line by default, `$p` means for the last line (`$`) execute the command `p` (print).