# Get the last line in progress bar using wget

Tags: python, python-2.7, wget

I am trying to STDOUT the wget results to a text file and just wanted to get the last line of the progress bar in the results.

Here is the sample of my results.

```
--2018-02-01 11:16:45--  http://www.stackoverflow.com/
Resolving www.stackoverflow.com (www.stackoverflow.com)... 151.101.1.69, 151.101.65.69, 151.101.129.69, ...
Connecting to www.stackoverflow.com (www.stackoverflow.com)|151.101.1.69|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 301 Moved Permanently
Location: https://stackoverflow.com/ [following]
--2018-02-01 11:16:45--  https://stackoverflow.com/
Resolving stackoverflow.com (stackoverflow.com)... 151.101.1.69, 151.101.65.69, 151.101.129.69, ...
Connecting to stackoverflow.com (stackoverflow.com)|151.101.1.69|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 254160 (248K) [text/html]
Saving to: â€˜/dev/nullâ€™


/dev/null             0%[                    ]       0  --.-KB/s               
/dev/null            20%[===>                ]  50.27K   248KB/s               
/dev/null            75%[==============>     ] 186.90K   464KB/s               
/dev/null           100%[===================>] 248.20K   514KB/s    in 0.5s    

2018-02-01 11:16:46 (514 KB/s) - â€˜/dev/nullâ€™ saved [254160/254160]
```

This is how I get it

```
wget -O /dev/null --progress=bar:force www.stackoverflow.com 2>> log_browse.txt
```

How do I output it in the file showing only this?

```
--2018-02-01 11:16:45--  http://www.stackoverflow.com/
Resolving www.stackoverflow.com (www.stackoverflow.com)... 151.101.1.69, 151.101.65.69, 151.101.129.69, ...
Connecting to www.stackoverflow.com (www.stackoverflow.com)|151.101.1.69|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 301 Moved Permanently
Location: https://stackoverflow.com/ [following]
--2018-02-01 11:16:45--  https://stackoverflow.com/
Resolving stackoverflow.com (stackoverflow.com)... 151.101.1.69, 151.101.65.69, 151.101.129.69, ...
Connecting to stackoverflow.com (stackoverflow.com)|151.101.1.69|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 254160 (248K) [text/html]
Saving to: â€˜/dev/nullâ€™


/dev/null           100%[===================>] 248.20K   514KB/s    in 0.5s    

2018-02-01 11:16:46 (514 KB/s) - â€˜/dev/nullâ€™ saved [254160/254160]
```

Just the last line of the progress...

Comment: `tail -n 1 file`?

Comment: @tripleee I'm sorry, not familiar with tail. How should I write it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Print just the last line of a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3080693/print-just-the-last-line-of-a-file)

Comment: Why is this tagged [tag:python] and [tag:python-2.7]? Your question seems to be about a shell command.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [tail command](https://shapeshed.com/unix-tail/) to read the file from the bottom.

```
wget -O /dev/null --progress=bar:force www.stackoverflow.com 2>> log_browse.txt
tail -n 1 log_browse.txt
```

-n 1 --> Gets the last line. You can change that by changing the number EX: to get last two line use -n 2