# how to print variables after each file with awk

Tags: awk

Expanding on [Print the last line of a file, from the CLI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3080693/print-the-last-line-of-a-file-from-the-cli)

I'm calling `awk` and passing `*` to process all files in the folder, but can't seem to figure out how to dump my variables after *each* file.

- The `END` keyword seems to run *only after all* files have completed:

  - `awk -F"'" '/export const/ { print $0 } END { print "done" }' *`
  - `awk -F"'" '/export const/ { CLSNM = $0 } END {print CLSNM }' *`
- And these don't fire at all (no output):

  - `awk -F"'" '/export const/ { CLSNM = $0 } NR==filesize { print CLSNM }' *`
  - `awk -F"'" '/export const/ { CLSNM = $0 } NR==LNR { print CLSNM }' *`

I'm on MacOS using `GNU Awk 5.1.0, API: 3.0 (GNU MPFR 4.1.0, GNU MP 6.2.1)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Action you are looking to be done should be covered with `ENDFILE`, try following code once. This is a GNU `awk` option, should work for your shown versioned of `awk`.

```
awk -F"'" '/export const/ { CLSNM = $0 } ENDFILE{ print CLSNM;CLSNM="" }' *
```

***2nd solution:*** without `EBNDFILE` option try following, should work with any `awk` version.

```
awk -F"'" 'FNR==1 && CLSNM{ print CLSNM; CLSNM=""} /export const/ { CLSNM = $0 } END{if(CLSNM){print CLSNM}}' *
```

Comment: conversely, `BEGINFILE` also turned out to be useful!